# Cartesian product of two lists of different types (Haskell)

Tags: list, haskell, cartesian-product

I'm (very) new to Haskell and I'm trying to solve what I think is a simple problem:

I want to create a list of the Cartesian product of two lists of different types: eg. one contains characters and one contains integers.

```
   ['A','B','C']
```

and the infinite list:

```
    [1..]
```

I'm trying to get an output where each of my letters is suffixed with a number: eg.

```
    ["A1", "B1", "C1", "A2", "B2"..]
```

I've been attempting this using things I've read online, however I'm struggling. As I understand it, I want to convert my integer list to a string using 'show'. My code is below:

```
    combinations xs cs = (,) <$> xs (show <$> cs)
```

Where xs and cs are passed in my function as ['A','B','C'] and [1..] respectively.

However I receive this error:

```
   Couldn't match expected type ‘[String] -> [a0]’
              with actual type ‘[Char]’
```

I'd really appreciate any ideas as I've been struggling for a while.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
(,) <$> xs (show <$> cs)
```

parses as

```
(,) <$> (xs (show <$> cs))
```

Note that here you are calling `xs` as a function, with `show <$> cs` as its argument. That can't be right: `xs` is a String!

Since you seem to be trying to program in applicative style, you probably meant to write something of the form

```
f <$> a <*> b
```

In your case,

```
f = (,)
a = xs
b = show <$> cs
```

So, you meant to write:

```
(,) <$> xs <*> (show <$> cs)
```

This is sorta close to what you wanted, but there are a few problems. First, its type is `[(Char, String)]`, where you wanted them joined up as strings. That can be fixed by using `(:)` instead of `(,)`.

Second, since one list is infinite, you need to process that as your "outermost loop" - if it's an inner loop, the fact that it never ends will mean your other loops never progress. When using `[]` as an Applicative, the "outer loop" is the first thing you map over.

So, we might try:

```
(,) <$> (show <$> cs) <*> xs
```

Note I've gone back to `(,)` for a moment to highlight something:

```
Prelude> take 5 $ (,) <$> (show <$> cs) <*> xs
[("1",'A'),("1",'B'),("1",'C'),("2",'A'),("2",'B')]
```

Now we get the pairs you want, but `(:)` won't work on them anymore because they're in the wrong order. So, you need to use a different function, one like `(:)` but which takes its arguments in the other order. Happily, it is easy to produce such a function: it's simply `flip (:)`:

```
Prelude> take 5 $ (flip (:)) <$> (show <$> cs) <*> xs
["A1","B1","C1","A2","B2"]
```

Comment: Surely this produces a list of pairs, rather than a list of concatenated strings? I'm not in a position to test right now but think it should work with `(:)` instead of `(,)`

Comment: Boy, I missed a lot of subtleties to this question, didn't I? @hskjskj If exactly one of the lists is infinite, you can still make progress by putting it first, and then reordering the arguments of your function to account for that.

Comment: @hskjskj In this case, putting the infinite list first helps, as amalloy pointed out. The general case where both lists can be infinite is more tricky, since you need a careful enumeration of all cases so to not get too focused on an infinite proper part of that (like your `A1,A2,A3,...` sequence). For handling that issue, some packages help (e.g. the `Omega` monad) but I don't recommend you use those until you are quite familiar with Haskell.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. That makes loads of sense now about the infinite inner loop!